# How to get UIDatePicker value in the UILabel on button click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please help me to get the value of `UIDatePicker` to `UILabel` on button click for an iPhone application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an outlet and then just ask its value

```
-(IBAction)OnButtonClick:(id)sender
{
   NSDate *date = datePicker.date;
   label.text = [date description];
}
```

Comment: Here is my answer: 

- (IBAction) timeChange: (id)sender
{

 NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
 [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 NSString *theTime;
 theTime =  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[myDatePicker date]];
 showDate.text = theTime; 
}

Answer (score 2):

```
 DatePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];

    [DatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

    //[DatePicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];

    [DatePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];

    [DatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDate:) 

forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];



-(void) doneButton

{

  [self updateDate:DatePicker];    //calling this fuction on inside the button

}




-(void)updateDate:(UIDatePicker *)sender

{
    NSDate *date = self.DatePicker.date;

    _dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [_dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    DateTextField.text = [_dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Maybe a bit of explanation could be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.0

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let date: NSDate = timePicker.date
    label.text = date.description
}
```