# NSDate - Getting date from custom action sheet date picker

Tags: ios, datepicker, nsdate

How can i access date from on click of Done button in my action sheet of a DatePicker:

```
 -(IBAction)doneBtnClick:(id)sender{   

 ......  
     else if([sender tag]==203)  
     {  
         NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:pickerDate.date];  

         NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
         [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];  

    //[self.lblDateSelected setAttributedText:strDate];

    //[pickerDate setDate:[NSDate date]];


           model.items.purchaseDate = [pickerDate setDate:[NSDate date]];  //error here!
```

purchaseDate is of type NSDate here.

Comment: you mean you want to get date from piker or set date to piker? if you want to get date on button click check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231305/how-to-get-uidatepicker-value-in-the-uilable-on-button-click)

Comment: what u add **pickerDate** at here